# Как в цикле обратиться к следующему элементу списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```py
list = [111, 222, 333]
for item in list:
    if item == 111:
        # заменить значение следующего элемента (222) на какое-то
```

Есть ли более простой способ, чем `list[list.index(item)+1]=xxx`?

Comment: И кто сюда ставит минусы?...

Comment: Насчёт "простой" что вы имеете в виду? Вариант с `index` по идее самый простой и короткий.

Comment: @чистов_n  я сюда ставлю минусы. За абсолютно бессмысленный заголовок, не имеющий отношения к самому вопросу.

Comment: @Эникейщик я когда вижу плохой заголовок, часто его правлю или просто пишу автору чтобы он его исправил, а не так как вы, просто молча ставить минусы, это странно.

Comment: @чистов_n я пока что писал ответ и не успел.

Answer (score 3):

С использованием функции `enumerate`:

```py
lst=[111,222,333]
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item==111:
        lst[i+1] = 125
        #          ^^^ значение на которое вам нужно заменить
```

Про `enumerate` в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 1):

Если допустимо создать новый список, а не менять старый, то есть ещё такой вариант (не самый эффективный):

```py
lst = [111,222,333]
lst = [125 if b == 111 else a for a, b in zip(lst, [None] + lst)]
```

Comment: Вместо zip можно [itertools.pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) использовать (правда он только начиная с Python 3.10 появился)

Comment: `it = iter(lst); next(it, None); ...zip(lst, it)...`